# How to access .html file that's located in the theme folder from the browser?

Tags: templates, rewrite-rules

By default you cannot access a file inside the theme folder directly from the browser, what changes should I make to make an exception?

Comment: Just wondering why are you trying to access a file directly there?

Comment: My client requested it because he has a script that can only work on a non-wordpress file. I could simply put it in the root folder but I think it's not safe.

Comment: *a script that can only work on a non-wordpress file* why would this be the case?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I didn't bother to ask. It's just an additional request that's not part of the initial agreement. :-O

Comment: What does the script do?

Comment: It's a billing system that's embedded through iframe.

Comment: That doesn't sound very secure, is there a reason why the file needs to be placed in the theme file? Why not place it in the root or another directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default you cannot access a file inside the theme folder directly from the browser

But that's [just not true](http://techcrunch.com/wp-content/themes/vip/tctechcrunch2/style.css).

Comment: This is true. Also, for the original question of the author, any HTML file (placed inside the theme folder) can be accessed directly from the browser. As per the `.htaccess` rules for WordPress permalink, any direct access to files isn't blocked.

Answer (score 1):

if you just embed it by iframe, what does it matter where it is located? put it in a designated folder for it.

Sounds like a horrible solution thou...

Comment: Well my assumption is that placing it along with most crucial files of Wordpress is not safe. Yeah it is. That's what my client wants and he knows it's a horrible solution.

Comment: Why would it not be safe? if the 'billing' script just does what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Make a folder in the root of the site called /files and put it there instead.

Answer (score -3):

You can access via the following method.

"yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/~theme_folder_name~/File.html"

Comment: `wp-content/themes` might not even *exist*, because you can move that to a completely different domain.